# how to take a sum value of selected column 's selected raws

Tags: java, mysql, sql, netbeans

I'm having two invoice id ( "inid") from indetails table using resultset which I made before . And I want to take sum value of qty of invoice table which equal to invoice ids ("inid") I took before.

Table name is " invoice ". And primary keys are "inid" (invoice id), "itid" (item id), "cuid" (customer id).

```
| inid | itid | cuid | itname | qty | sprice | total|
| 1    | 1    | 1    | item1  | 25  | 250    | 6250 |
| 2    | 1    | 1    | item2  | 15  | 250    | 3750 |
```

And this is my sql query.

```
try {
    ResultSet rs3 = db.getData("SELECT SUM(qty) AS Total FROM invoice WHERE inid='"  +   rs1.getInt("inid") + "'");

    while(rs3.next()){
        int val =  rs3.getInt("Total");
    }
}
catch (Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, this.getClass().getName() + "rs2 " + e);
}
```

I'm only having first raw's column "qty"'s value. I want to take the sum of whole value of "qty" which equals with "inid" (invoice ids)

Comment: This code looks fine, so whats the issue? if you give it an inid it will get sum of qty for all such values where inid is that. So what's exactly wrong? `I'm only having first raw's column "qty"'s value` because that is the only column with inid = 1, if you sent it 1

Comment: @HankyPanky from another resultset I'm having to inid s . inid = 1, inid=2. So I'm only having qty releated from inid = 1

Comment: Ok where do you output this int val?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way will be useful

```
try {

      ResultSet rs3 = db.getData("SELECT qty FROM invoice WHERE inid='"  +   rs1.getInt("inid") + "'");
int total=0;
       while(rs3.next()){
       total+=rs3.getInt("qty");
      }
System.out.println(total);

  }

  catch (Exception e) {

          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, this.getClass().getName() + "rs2 " + e);
  }
```

Comment: @HankyPanky from another resultset I'm having to inid s . inid = 1, inid=2. So I'm only having qty releated from inid = 1

Comment: from System.ot.println I'm having value 0; Also there s an exception called, you don't have column call "total"

Comment: @user2507358 did you try my way?

Comment: I'm so sorry. First time I tried it with SUM part. Thats whay it went wrong. It is really working now. I appreciate whole of your support.

Answer (score 1):

You can use group by which give direct total of qty.

```
ResultSet rs3 = db.getData("SELECT SUM(qty) AS Total FROM invoice WHERE inid='"  +   rs1.getInt("inid") + "' GROUP BY inid");
```

Comment: from this query also I'm having inid=1's "qty"'s value. I want whole qty value equals to iniid s which I given.

Comment: can you please post your expected ans.so we can understand what u need

Comment: I want answer as 40. because qty=25 + qty= 15 =qty 40 . And also because they are in inid=1, inid=2 's raws.  I'm bring in inid=1, and inid=2 as results from a resultset I made before.

Comment: if you want total of both rows qty then why you need where clause in your query just remove where clause? or may be you are want to apply where on itid column.